# FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE event in itemrenderer not firing from as class

Tags: actionscript-3, air, itemrenderer

I have a CustomItemRenderer for List component and I set list label on onDataChange() event of this CustomItemRenderer. 
onDataChange event type is mx.events.FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE.

After some property changes on dataprovider, I'm trying to fire new mx.events.FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE in as class with

```
_view.EncoderList.dispatchEvent(new mx.events.FlexEvent(mx.events.FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));
```

Following, same process works for buttonClick fire,

```
_view.SplitBtn.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

So, what could be the reason I couldn't fire CustomRenderer's FlexEvent ?

Note: debugged and sure its not firing.

Comment: When dispatching the event, try setting the bubble-parameter to true.

Comment: @codingbuddha sorry, I couldn't understand bubble-parameter mean ?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of the FlexEvent, like most events, looks like this:

```
public function FlexEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false):void
```

Which means, you have to change your code to

```
_view.EncoderList.dispatchEvent(new mx.events.FlexEvent(mx.events.FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE, true));
```

to enable Event-Bubbling for this event. Otherwise the event can only be listened to if you bind a listener to the dispatching item itself

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fire FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE event manually yet, but when I do

`_myListDataProvider.Refresh()` ,

FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE is already fired:)